# SVD of row matrix using QR

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I want to reach to full SVD in faster way.
Since this involves hardware implementation, rather than designing things from scratch I want to use already available blocks:

a) QR decomposition
b) Matrix multiplication and basic  manipulations

Since QR do have role of householder there should an optimal way to reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Let $A=QR$. Then $AA^T = RR^T$ and $A^TA=R^TR$. Now the singular vectors are given by eigenvectors of these matrices. Also singular values are given by eigenvalues of any of them (both will have same eigenvalues). There are really efficient methods to find eigenvalues from the cholesky decomposition of a matrix (since $AA^T=RR^T$ where $R$ is uppertriangular, you essentially have cholesky decomposition). Once you find the eigenvalues, it boils to solving linear system of equations. Say that you have a linear system of the form $CC^Tx=b$ for any given triangular matrix $C$ and vector $b$. Now you can solve the linear system $Cy=b$ first. Since $C$ is triangular, this can be done very fast by back-substitution. Then you can solve for the system $C^Tx=y$.

Comment: Solving equations will be a task itself in hardware.  Can having a block to do SVD of square matrix help?

Comment: @JayPrakash sorry didn't get you. You said you wanted to use QR decomposition to calculate SVD right?. Solving systems of equations with triangular matrices is very straightforward via back-substitution and is the standard approach. Please look up on that.

Comment: @JayPrakash feel free to reach out to me on my username.at.gmail if you need more clarity

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271901/svd-of-row-matrix/2273002#2273002
This method worked for me for a vector.

Comment: SVD is a highly non-trivial concept compared to orthogonalization of a set of given vectors which is what is explained in the question you pointed.

Comment: yes but hardware design asks for loads of simplicity and I not being expert in RTL need to use available resources.